# DataTable in Angular How can I change the language

Tags: datatables, angular-ui-bootstrap

how to change language for DataTable from english to french in Angular 
this is my Code

```
<table #mytable *ngIf="utilisateurs" datatable class="row-border hover">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Nom</th>
        <th>Prenom</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Preference</th>
        <th>Pointe Vente</th>
        <th>Type Utilisateur</th>
        <th>Date Creation</th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let u of utilisateurs">
        <td>{{ u.nom }}</td>
        <td>{{ u.prenom }}</td>
        <td>{{ u.email }}</td>
        <td>{{ u.preference }}</td>
        <td>{{ u.nomPointeVente }}</td>
        <td>{{ u.typeUtilisateur }}</td>
        <td>{{ u.dateCreation }}</td>
        <td><i title="editer"  (click)="editer(u)"  class="fas fa-user-edit" style="margin:10px; "   
            data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModaledit"></i>  <i title="supprimer" class="fas fa-user-times" style="margin:10px; "></i>  <i title="details" class="fas fa-info-circle"style="margin:10px; "></i>  </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

and this is the correction in JQuery Haw can i do this in angular

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "language": {
            "url": "dataTables.german.lang"
        }
    } );
} );
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean - can you provide more details? An example? If you mean the labels provided by Datatables (e.g. for page scrolling, and so on), then are you familiar with the Datatables [internationalisation plug-ins](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/i18n/)? [Here](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/i18n/French) is one for French.

Comment: Also take a look at the [internationalisation](https://datatables.net/manual/i18n) page in the main manual. Have a go at implementing something - if you have a specific problem, you can ask a specific question.

Comment: is so simple i USE  datatable in angular and  i want to  change the language to french how can i  do this  in angular   ''<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').dataTable( {
            "language": {
                "url": "dataTables.german.lang"
            }
        } );
    } );
</script>''

Comment: Your code has nothing to do with Angular; it is jQuery.

Comment: is not my code is an exemple in jQuery i search un exemple in angular

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good example of changing the language in datatables:
in your exemplecomponent.ts file

```
dtOptions: any  = {};

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dtOptions = {
      language: {
        processing:     "Traitement en cours...",
        search:         "Rechercher&nbsp;:",
        lengthMenu:    "Afficher _MENU_ &eacute;l&eacute;ments",
        info:           "Affichage de l'&eacute;lement _START_ &agrave; _END_ sur _TOTAL_ &eacute;l&eacute;ments",
        infoEmpty:      "Affichage de l'&eacute;lement 0 &agrave; 0 sur 0 &eacute;l&eacute;ments",
        infoFiltered:   "(filtr&eacute; de _MAX_ &eacute;l&eacute;ments au total)",
        infoPostFix:    "",
        loadingRecords: "Chargement en cours...",
        zeroRecords:    "Aucun &eacute;l&eacute;ment &agrave; afficher",
        emptyTable:     "Aucune donnée disponible dans le tableau",
        paginate: {
            first:      "Premier",
            previous:   "Pr&eacute;c&eacute;dent",
            next:       "Suivant",
            last:       "Dernier"
        },
        aria: {
            sortAscending:  ": activer pour trier la colonne par ordre croissant",
            sortDescending: ": activer pour trier la colonne par ordre décroissant"
        }
    },
      pagingType: 'full_numbers',
      pageLength: 10,
      processing: true,
    };
  }
```

Comment: Please, I'm using your example, but I want to know, how can the language be changed automatically, not by refreshing?

Answer (score 1):

1. Create class export for your language (mine: french.ts)

   ```
   export class DatatableLanguage {
       public static datatableFrench = {
            processing: "Traitement en cours...",
            search: "Rechercher&nbsp;:",
            lengthMenu: "Afficher _MENU_ &eacute;l&eacute;ments",
            info: "Affichage de l'&eacute;lement _START_ &agrave; _END_ sur _TOTAL_ &eacute;l&eacute;ments",
            infoEmpty: "Affichage de l'&eacute;lement 0 &agrave; 0 sur 0 &eacute;l&eacute;ments",
            infoFiltered: "(filtr&eacute; de _MAX_ &eacute;l&eacute;ments au total)",
            infoPostFix: "",
            loadingRecords: "Chargement en cours...",
            zeroRecords: "Aucun &eacute;l&eacute;ment &agrave; afficher",
            emptyTable: "Aucune donnée disponible dans le tableau",
            paginate: {
                first: "Premier",
                previous: "Pr&eacute;c&eacute;dent",
                next: "Suivant",
                last: "Dernier"
            },
            aria: {
                sortAscending: ": activer pour trier la colonne par ordre croissant",
                sortDescending: ": activer pour trier la colonne par ordre décroissant"
            }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Import it in your component file and use it in your `[dtOptions]`

   ```
    import {DatatableLanguage } from "../.."

    public dtOptions: any = {}

    ngOnInit(): void { 
        this.dtOptions = {
            language : DatatableLanguage.datatableFrench
        }     
    }
   ```
3. in your HTML file : `<table datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions">`

Comment: Please, I'm using your example, but I want to know, how can the language be changed automatically, not by refreshing?